# DL360 gen7 + 2 SSD Raid 10 crashing and amber lighting nonstop - it works fine with 2 SAS HDD

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, ssd, data-recovery

Thats it pretty much, I have this recently acquired DL360 with 2 300gb SAS HDDs. Every thing works fine with them in RAID 10: no crashes, no sudden amber lights, no amber lights after every reboot, no problem disconnecting one disk to force the recovery mode... Everything works as a charm. I then bought 2 120gb SSDs from ADATA (SU650) in order to get faster readings (the machine gonna be a BGP server, I dont need too much storage but I definitively need stability, if it stops some thousands of people runs out of Internets). Well, after I delete the old raid and create the new one with the new drives, it seems fine until the first reboot, or the first anything. Sometimes the installed OS keeps running but fails load mos of the boot files, sometimes it reaches the login prompt but returns errors nonstoped, amber lights everywhere... I tried to install Windows and its bsod everywhere and the amber lights turns the room's walls orange.

Am I forgetting something? Are there any special configuration for using the raid and the docks with SSD diskis? I dont understand. Im specially worried because I already ordered a second server, a similar one, for virtualization. And I cant use SAS disks in it, its gonna need A LOT of SSDs.

Any advice is welcome, Im a newb with servers, this is my first one.

Thanks